# Viewing hierarchy in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, hierarchy

What are my options for viewing hierarchies in iOS? In OSX I have the option of using `NSOutlineView`. Ideally I should be able to support at least 3 levels.

Answer (score 3):

Not much. Table views support sections and rows, which gives you 2 levels.

You could use a UICollectionView and roll your own hierarchy of data, but I don't think there is an equivalent to NSOutlineView in iOS. The UI Elements are designed for the small screen on a phone, where you don't really have enough space to present multiple levels of data. Apple added a few extra controls like a split view controller for iPad, but not really an outline viewer.

The norm on iOS is to use multiple levels of master/detail views. You drill down from the top level item by item until you get to the detail you're looking for.